# how to display listview inside alert in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-layout

i am using rflutter_alert plugin to handle alerts in my App using Flutter 
but i have an issue when I put listView for parameter content 
other widgets like Text work without issues

i am getting the following error

> Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
>   RenderViewport does not support returning intrinsic dimensions.

```
Expanded(
  child: Card(
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: content.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text(content[index]["doctor_name"]),
          onTap: (){
            Alert(
              context: context,
              title: doctors[index]["doctor_name"],
              content: ListView(children: <Widget>[
                Text(doctors[index]["major"]),
                Text(doctors[index]["hospital"]),
              ],)
            ).show();
          },
          );
        }),
  ),
)
```

this is the pluing url 
[rflutter_alert](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert)

could you please help in this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and wrap it into container and set width/height

```
   onTap: (){
        Alert(
          context: context,
          title: doctors[index]["doctor_name"],
          content: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: ListView(children: <Widget>[
               Text(doctors[index]["major"]),
               Text(doctors[index]["hospital"]),
          ],))
        ).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `shrinkWrap: true` in your `ListView` of Alert Dialog.

Like below.

```dart
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('$index'),
              onTap: () {
                Alert(
                  context: context,
                  title: 'Title',
                  content: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true, // Like here
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('Test'),
                      Text('Test'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ).show();
              },
            );
          }),
```